# Different redirect uri for same client - Keycloak + Angular + SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am developing a meal planner app. I am using Angular 10 (Front end) + SpringBoot 2.0 (Back end) + OAuth2 with Keycloak (as Authentication Server).

When the user signs up, he provides the below information:

1. sign up info - email + username + password
2. application specific info - preferred diet type, nutritional requirements

**My questions:**

1. The nutritional requirements is a map with about 15 entries. So I would prefer to store sign up info in Keycloak server and application specific info in the application DB (My SQL) - Is this approach advisable?
2. After Keycloak signup, I want the redirect uri to be an intermediary page as shown below:

[Login and registeration flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMAfB.png)

How do I give 2 different redirect uri for the same client?

Answer (score 0):

You could always redirect to /showPlan and if you get a 404 on the diet-info you redirect to /diet-info.

In my opinion the diagram and your question do not match, because in the diagram signup and adding diet-info are 2 seperate steps

Comment: Hi Ludi, signup with Keycloak + add diet-info in application together form the user registration. Something like: you log into Gmail, and it tells you 'Help us secure your account - select a recovery option'.

Comment: So you are using custom attributes on the keycloak signup page ? Like here: https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-user-registration ?

I guess you just read the custom attributes from the user and store them in you desired database